# adding google map in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

i am develope web application for factory i need to add google map with location of factory
in contact us web page.any help i am just beginging with web development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Map API is just javascript. Which can be used in any  web technology

follow this link you will get what you are looking for
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Answer (score 5):

Easy way [here](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72644) does all the work for you.

> **Embedding a map into a website or blog**
>
> You can embed a simple map, a set of
>   driving directions, a local search, or
>   maps created by other users. Here's
>   how:
>
> 1. Ensure that the map you'd like to embed appears in the current map
>      display.
> 2. Click Link to this page in the top-right corner of the map.
> 3. In the box that pops up, copy the HTML under 'Paste HTML to embed in
>      website,' and paste it into the source
>      code of your website or blog.
>
> If you'd like to adjust the size of the map before you embed it, just click
>   Customize and preview embedded map, select your preferred size, and take a
>   look at the preview map. Once you're happy with what you see, copy the HTML
>   that appears in the box at the bottom of the window.
>
> Keep in mind that you won't be able to embed Traffic maps, Mapplets, and some
>   other Maps features.

Comment: Yes, it seems like this is the right approach in this case. No need to implement any fancy javascript API when it is just to show the location of the factory.

Comment: @shmandor - if your customer requirements are to have a map on a contact us web page then the above instructions will allow you to do that. You don't need to do any coding to achieve this.

Comment: *Hanging my head in shame*  That is SO much an easier answer than mine.  +1 for a beautifully simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your beginning, maybe you should try to learn web development first. Javascript, post/get mechanics, HTML/CSS validation. Tackling Google Maps integration right at the beginning of your learning process might slow down your project evolution. It's my opinion.

To learn google maps api, try to start at this address :

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/introduction.html